# Parameter missing to calculate the Zener diode maximum current

Tags: datasheet, zener

I want to operate [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/dc39/0900766b814f43e4.pdf) 3.3V 5W Zener diode without any heatsink at a maximum ambient temperature of 55°C, and I want to estimate the maximum current at 55°C.

Maximum junction temperature Tj is given as 200°C. I think from the application note (page 6) one can calculate the maximum dissipated power Pd for 55°C and where Tj=200°C, and then figure out the maximum current as Pd/3.3V.

[image]

In the above formulas there is "lead-to-ambient thermal resistance" but it is not given in the datasheet.

How can the maximum current at 55°C be calculated without that parameter?

Comment: What are you using the zener for, anyway?

Answer (score 4):

The lead to ambient thermal resistance is external to the device and is basically the thermal properties of anything soldered/attached to the leads. Imagine it as mini heatsinks on each lead to take heat power away from the leads and keep them cooler.

You have to devise a system for removing heat from the leads if you are pushing the envelope on power. Possibly this picture might help: -

[image]

I've highlighted in red the bits you might need to add to improve the removal of heat power from the Zener diode leads. This bits will have a thermal resistance called \$\theta_{LA}\$. And, if you soldered the zeners into a circuit board and did not apply much copper to the pads if would be a value of several tens of °C per watt.

Maybe you should use the calculator [I linked to you](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/638434/20218) in my answer to your previous question?

Comment: Btw in that previous question did you read in question that the regulator is mounted on Nucelo board. Have you thought they might have used very large copper to heatsink it? Because in their table for current limitations given for various VIN. Apparently the regulator can dissipate about 1.6W. (7V-5V)x.8. Or, (9-5)x.45. Or, (12-5)x.25. Maybe they have liquid cooling. Maybe they’ve got a lot of copper area on the PCB. Did your answer consider that the regulator is mounted on the Nucleo board?

Comment: That's up to you to consider and it's up to you to provide all necessary information.  I didn't see any mention of a Nucelo board (and I have just double checked that). And, if I follow the link (that takes me to a Nucleo board), how would anyone be able to estimate how much copper they have used without design files being made available. That's your job to find out @user1245 <-- if you want to use it then you need to ensure it's good enough (water cooled or not).

Comment: Yes the question could be more explicit. Its because the main question was not about it. Anyway the Nucleo board has a table for current limitations due to VIN in its manual: https://community.st.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=0683W00000UiEo6&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05T3W00001NQibN&page=0 But they dont mention any temperature.